# Best algorithm to compare two colors

Tags: image-processing, colors, pixel

when I look for a way to compare two pixels there are so many ways to do that:

```
Lab, L*ab, L*a*b*, HSL, CIE-L*ab, Delta-E 1976, CMC l:c, Delta-LCH, ...
```

I want to use javascript implementing that.

Which space/algorithm is the best to compare two RGB colors?

Comment: I believe all the variations on "Lab" are the same.

Comment: P.S. The "best" will depend on what you're trying to accomplish, which you haven't done.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for your opinion. as you see on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) there are some variations of Lab. How can they be the same? My final goal is just comparing based on a space near to human eyes.

Comment: The only variation I see on Wikipedia is Hunter Lab, which I'd never heard of before. `CIE L*a*b*` is the standard.